# How to avoid object collection by garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

I have some objects in my code which are not invoked in everyloop,But they are useful in future when some forced termination from loop,unpredictable error etc happens, So how to make sure that this **objects** are not ever **collected by garbage collector**.

For example : I have one class so I dont want GC to perform any Garbage collection on this class

Answer (score 4):

If the objects are valuable and expensive to create, you should hang on to them in a field in your class. You could create a Map that would act sort of like a cache and grab them out of the Map when you're ready to use them again.

Answer (score 1):

If they are useful in the future you have a reference to these objects somewhere. This is enough to ensure that they will never be garbage collected.

Comment: But as I have stated they can be use once blue moon,So thus it not reffered regularly ,and it happens to be collected by GC

Comment: If there is a reference from a living thread it won't get collected, no matter how long you don't use it. If you don't have a reference ... how do you intend to use it later on?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a strong reference to the object, Doing this will always ensure that your object will not be GCed. I would also leave such things to the Garbage collector which I think is smarter than us(with all due respect) when it comes to memory management

Comment: I respect ur answer but as I have stated it will be used in future scope so tht's why,I need that object .Just I have to make sure it is not GCed,and even my CPU is not used tht much .

Comment: @klobin - in that case. *klobin's* answer would work. You just need to keep strong references for those objects and ensure that the container that keeps these references isn't GCed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the scope of your variables. as long as they are in scope they should not be garbage collected.

Comment: Is there any way that this objects always are in scope of execution.

Comment: create a static Map/List and put objects there.

Comment: An object can be collected even if a reference is still in scope. To be collected, an object must be *unreachable*, which is different. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24380219/1441122).

Comment: yes Stuart is correct, but by putting objects in static collection  there will always a strong reference pointing it.

Comment: Depending on your application always having a strong reference could be really heavy on memory.

Answer (score 0):

***Garbage Collector Simply Avoids The Object Which Have Any Reference In The Code Further. So If You Want Any Object To Never Get Collected By G.C. Until The Execution Of Your Code.  Just Have A Global Reference To That Object.***