# Java - How does automatic garbage collection work for LinkedList?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection

In C++ you need to manually delete nodes in the LinkedList:

```
  Node* node1 = new Node(s);
  Node* node2 = new Node(s);
  Node* node3 = new Node(s);

  node1 -> next = node2;
  node2 -> next = node3;

  //remove node2 by: 
  delete node2;
  node1 -> next = node3;
```

For Java (it's my first 2 days learning it) how does automatic
garbage collection know when to take action? Would:

```
    node1.next = node3;
```

be adequate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An object in java will become eligible for garbage collection once no references to it are in scope.

So if you have a singly linked list like so

```
(1) -> (2) -> (3)
```

And assume `head = node 1`

Then yes, setting `head.next = head.next.next` will allow `node 2` to be GC'd at some point.

However, in your example, your `node2` could not go away until you explicitly declare

`node2 = null` in addition to `node1.next = node3` because the reference as `node2` would keep it in scope.

Note that `node2 = null` is not actually doing ANYTHING to the `Node` object that `node2` used to point to. Instead it simply sets the reference (since all objects in java are really pointers) to null.

Comment: "In scope" isn't quite right, though. Scope is a lexical structure which is only loosely related to object lifetime. Objects will become eligible for GC when they are no longer *reachable* by any running code, which is not the same as "in scope".

Comment: That's a fair distinction. I suppose it would be more appropriate to say that most of the time, the GC is able to pick up objects because their references go out of scope, thus making them unreachable. Thanks for the improved technical explanation!

Comment: Actually, your edited answer isn't quite right either, since an object *can* become unreachable while a reference to it is still in scope. Basically as soon as the compiler can prove that a reference is never read anymore, it is free to reuse the local variable in the frame for something else, at which point the object in question no longer has any references and is eligible for GC. Raymond Chen explains this (for C#, although Java is similar) in his blog post [When does an object become eligible for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx)

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: you are right, similar things for Java are discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24380219/2711488) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488)

Answer (score 2):

The Java garbage collector PERIODICALLY runs through the entire object reference map to find and delete objects that are unreferenced or cyclically referenced. You can hint the JVM to start an iteration of garbage collection, but there is no way for you to pragmatically instruct the JVM to garbage collect deterministically.

in your case

```
node1.next = node3;
```

would be adequate as `node2` will no longer have any objects referencing it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you modify the `LinkedList` in a way such that there are no more references to `node2`, the garbage collector can release its memory. In other words, `node1.next = node3;` should be enough, assuming there are no other references to `node2`.