# how to create cleaner for map of string to file handles?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-9, resource-cleanup

I have a class

```
class Something {
    private Map<String, RandomAccessFile> map = new LinkedHashMap<>() {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(...) { also closes the file if it returns true; }

        @Override
        public RandomAccessFile remove(Object filename) { closes the file too; }
    };
}
```

This is a map of filename to the file handle.  The idea is to keep a few files open, so that member functions of the Something class can write to any of the open files.

Now I'd like to override finalize so that when the object goes out of scope, we close all files.  But finalize is deprecated.  So the idea is to call cleaner.register(map, runnable) where runnable gets all the RandomAccessFile in 'map' and closes each.  I.e. something like `cleaner.register(map, () -> map.values().forEach(close file))`.  But this makes runnable have a reference to the map, so the map can never become unreachable - class LinkedHashMap.LinkedValues is not a static class.

Any ideas how to do accomplish this?

Comment: It would be nice if the signature of register were `public Cleanable register(Object obj, Consumer<Object> action)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the object whose reachability should control the cleanup and the data needed for the cleanup.

In your case, the lifetime of the `Something` instance would determine whether the files are still in use, whereas the map instance can be used during the cleanup action, assuming that you keep the map private and never hand it out.

There are still some important points to care for. The [documentation of `Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) says:

> The cleaning action could be a lambda but all too easily will capture the object reference, by referring to fields of the object being cleaned, preventing the object from becoming phantom reachable. Using a static nested class, as above, will avoid accidentally retaining the object reference.

When you use the lambda expression `() -> map.values().forEach(close file))` and `map` is a field access of the current `Something` instance, you have implicitly captured `this`. But even if you fix the cleaner, to let it only reference the map instance, there’s the problem that the map itself is an anonymous subclass of `LinkedHashMap` and anonymous inner classes always have an implicit reference to their outer instance.

You can fix both by performing the initialization in a static context:

```java
class Something {
    private Map<String, RandomAccessFile> map = initializeMapAndCleaner(this);

    static final Cleaner CLEANER = Cleaner.create();

    static Map<String, RandomAccessFile> initializeMapAndCleaner(Object instance) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, RandomAccessFile> map = new LinkedHashMap<>() {
            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, RandomAccessFile> eldest) {
                /*also closes the file if it returns true;*/
            }

            @Override
            public RandomAccessFile remove(Object filename) { /*closes the file too;*/ }
        };
        CLEANER.register(instance, () -> map.values().forEach(f -> {/*close file*/}));
        return map;
    }
}
```

By using a `static` method, there can’t be any implicit reference to `this` and the explicit reference provided in the `instance` parameter has been deliberately typed as `Object`, to make it harder to accidentally accessing a member in the map class or cleanup action.

But note that the `LinkedHashMap` does not guaranty that all removal operations go through that single overridden `remove` method. Further, replacement operations do not use `remove`. It may work for your internal use when that `remove` is the only operation (besides `put`) the `Something` class uses, but in this case, it would also be possible and cleaner to make file closing the caller’s duty.

---

That said, you should not implement the cleaner at all. If all the cleanup is doing, is to close the `RandomAccessFile`, it’s obsolete as there is already a cleaner closing the underlying resource when `RandomAccessFile` becomes unreachable without being closed. If relying on that cleaner feels hacky, you’re on the right track. But relying on `Something`’s cleaner is in no way better.

Generally, variable scopes and object reachability are only remotely connected. See [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24376768/2711488) or [finalize() called on strongly reachable objects in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488) for a connected real life problem. But of course, the timing issues described in [When is the finalize() method called in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2506488/2711488) apply to cleaners as well. The garbage collector may never run, e.g. when there’s enough memory, or it may run but not collect all unreachable objects, e.g. when it reclaimed enough memory for the application to proceed.

When you want to clean up at the end of a variable’s scope, the [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is the way to go. You only have to implement `AutoCloseable` or a subtype of it, providing a `close()` method that will close all files.

```java
class Something implements Closeable { // java.io.Closeable is suitable here
    …

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        for(RandomAccessFile f: map.values()) f.close();
        map.clear();
    }
}
```

Then you can easily say

```java
try(Something sth = new Something(…)) {
    // use sth
}
// safely closed
```

Comment: Got it, it's not needed to use Cleaner here.  However in your example `CLEANER.register(instance, () -> map.values().forEach(...))` the cleanable has a reference to map.values(), which is special non-nested class which contains a reference to map, so it wouldn't work right? However, as you pointed out, I changed my code to not use cleaner, and will make it implement AutoCloseable soon. @Holger.

Comment: @snaran it has a direct reference to `map`; the `values()` method is only invoked when the cleaner runs. But, as said, the important point is that the reachability of the `Something` instance determines when the cleaner may run, not the map instance. In the code above, the first argument to `CLEANER.register(…)` is not the map.