# Lifetime of object declared in constructor (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, garbage-collection

I am running calling a native function in Kotlin that takes a Unix file descriptor as a parameter. After the native function runs for a few minutes it report EBADF.

The code looks something like

```kotlin
class A(val file: ParcelFileDescriptor) : AutoCloseable {
    private var fileDes: Int = -1
    private external fun longRunningNativeFn(fd : Int) : FnResult

    init {
        fileDes = file.fd
    }
    
    fun process() : FnResult {
        longRunningNativeFn(fileDes)
    }
    override fun close {
    }
}
```

The file object passed into the constructor is not held anywhere else.

My working theory is that since `file` is only used in the `init` block, `file` then becomes a candidate for garbage collection so after a few minutes when the garbage collector kicks in, the `file` object calls close resulting in the native code getting a bad file descriptor.

So

- is this theory correct?
- If so what determines the lifetime of parameters in the constructor?
- Does adding `file.close()` to the `close` function extend the lifetime of `file` for the duration of the class?

**Note** after adding the `file.close()`, I am no longer getting the BADF in my native code. Even though as @Ivo points out adding val to the primary constructor makes `file` a class member, the JRE might be smart enough to see nothing is using `file` and garbage collect it early since it needs to stick around until `close` is called

Answer (score 2):

It's not merely a parameter of the constructor. You defined it as a property by writing `val` in front of it. You can access it throughout the entire lifetime of the instance. If you only want to have it as parameter you need to leave out the `val` like

```
class A(file: ParcelFileDescriptor) : AutoCloseable {
```

As for the lifetime if you write it like that, I personally don't know but I assume it gets garbage collected after the last init block but that's just a guess. And of course it also matters whether there are other references to that object outside of that class. I also have no idea why that EBADF happens

Comment: When `file` is a field of the `A` instance, it prevents the garbage collection of the object referenced by `file`, as long as the `A` instance is reachable. So it all depends on how the `A` instance is used. Worth reading [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24376768/2711488) and a similar related issue, [finalize() called on strongly reachable objects in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488). In short, it’s possible that the `A` instance gets garbage collected even while the `process()` method is executed.

Comment: I have noted in my question, that adding the file.close() to the close function sorts the issue out, by I, guess ensuring file remains reachable for the duration