# Garbage collection with closure of instance variable

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Does a reference to an instance variable keep the object around, or would it get garbage collected if it's not reachable?

```java
public class State {
    private int x = 10;
    
    Runnable runnable() {
        return () -> System.out.println(x);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       State state = new State();
       Runnable runnable = state.runnable();
       state = null;
       // Is the `state` object eligible for collection here?
       runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the `Runnable` lambda is capturing `this` (a reference to the `State` object). It is a strong reference.

Comment: @Slaw I don't think the Runnable is capturing `this`, it's just creating a copy of `x`. As `x` is a primitive, that's a copy of the value. If `x` wasn't a primitive, it would be a copy of the reference.

Comment: See here for the explanation about value copying with lambdas: https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-lambda-local-variable-closure

Comment: @scrhartley No, it's capturing `this`. You can test by modifying `x` after the lambda creation.

Comment: @scrhartley that isn’t correct. The link you shared is referring to local variables, but this is an instance variable.

Comment: As long as the code looks like shown in the question, i.e. `runnable` is never accessed, both, the `Runnable` and the captured `this` are eligible to garbage collection. See [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380219/2711488)

Comment: @Holger I modified the script so that runnable is executed. Please take a look, could `state` be garbage collected in this case?

Comment: @petabyte As long as the `Runnable` instance is strongly referenced, so is the `State` instance. Just like normal. Now, in your code, you don't keep a reference of the `Runnable` anywhere except in a local variable, meaning once the method returns, the `Runnable` is eligible for GC (and thus the `State` object). That's obviously ignoring the fact the method in question is the main method, and you don't start any non-daemon threads, which means the JVM will terminate once it returns.

Comment: @Slaw makes sense, thanks. In this case though, I see the lambda is capturing `this`, but why does it have to? If JVM knows that only `x` is required, could it just throw away everything else? I mean even just pointer to `x`

Comment: Because `x` is a field, and so it needs a reference to `this` so that it can always get the most up-to-date value. I suppose it's possible that JIT might optimize that by copying `x` if it were `final` or if JIT determines it's never modified, but I have no idea if that happens. Now, if you're asking why the JVM can't just keep a direct pointer to `x` instead of via `this`, well I would say in that scenario, if the `State` instance is GC'd, then what happens to `x`? The `x` field value is part of the object memory that's just been reclaimed (making `x` meaningless).

Comment: To build on @Slaw’s comment, such optimization is possible in practice by inlining the code of `State`’s constructor, the `runnable()` and the `run()` method into the caller, then transforming the caller to a form which simply uses the value `10` which would be written to `x` in the constructor in the print statement directly instead of reading `x`. This requires that either, no thread synchronization happens in-between or Escape Analysis proves that `State` is never seen by other threads. Then both, `State` and `Runnable` instances, are garbage collectible or never created in the first place.