# Does garbage collector actually remove objects going out of scope?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In my habitual understanding, a local variable becomes eligible for garbage collection as soon as the code has exited the block.

Here are my tests

```
@Test
public void testOutOfScopeGC() throws InterruptedException {
    MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Usage: " + memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage());
    try {
        int[] arr = new int[100000000];
        // arr = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Usage: " + memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage());
    System.gc();
    // wait for GC
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Heap Memory Usage after GC: " + memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage());
}
```

The result is

```
Heap Memory Usage: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 92115224(89956K) committed = 324534272(316928K) max = 954728448(932352K)
Heap Memory Usage: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 492115240(480581K) committed = 724566016(707584K) max = 954728448(932352K)
Heap Memory Usage after GC: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 412144528(402484K) committed = 724566016(707584K) max = 954728448(932352K)
```

We can see that the used part has not been reduced. In addition, I also tested the if block, and the result is the same

Then I uncomment the `arr = null;`, or just put `int[] arr = new int[100000000];` into a separate method, the result will be

```
Heap Memory Usage: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 90817568(88689K) committed = 324534272(316928K) max = 954728448(932352K)
Heap Memory Usage: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 490817584(479314K) committed = 724566016(707584K) max = 954728448(932352K)
Heap Memory Usage after GC: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 10809360(10556K) committed = 724566016(707584K) max = 954728448(932352K)
```

All code runs in the JDK 8.

Does it mean that if a large object is created inside a method, it needs to wait until the method is finished to be released, regardless of whether it's inside a block

Could someone kindly help explain this situation or provide relevant articles?

Comment: The key word is "eligible." There's no guarantee if or when the GC will run.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc-- "Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects. " the key word here is "suggests"

Comment: No. There is no bytecode instruction for exiting a local scope. *Ergo* the JVM cannot detect it, other than via the stack slot being reused for something else.

Comment: if  some variable was declared after the block (e.g. var s = "";) then most probably the *instance* ¹ pointed by `arr` will be collected (since the local variable *slot* will be re-used for the new variable. || **¹** BTW it is not the "*local variable becomes eligible for garbage collection*", but the instance that it references (assuming no other reference  is *live*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java bytecode itself has no concept of scopes, that is purely a thing understood by compilers. What the Java compiler does is use a *slot* for each variable in the code. A *slot* is allocated on the stack. From a compilers point of view, when a variable exists in a scope, and it goes out of the scope, that *slot* can be reused for a different variable.

If (and only if) that happens, and the new variable is assigned a new value, the *slot* is reassigned, and the object previously referenced by the slot becomes eligible for garbage collection. However, if the *slot* is not reused *after* the scope ended, the object referenced by the *slot* is still strongly referenced, and the referenced object will only become eligible for garbage collection on method exit (when the method and its *slots* are removed from the stack).

That is what happens here. If you decompile the bytecode (e.g. with `javap`), you'll get something like this (NOTE: I used Java 21 to compile, and IntelliJ to produce the bytecode representation, results may be different from Java 8 and using `javap`):

```
// access flags 0x1
public testOutOfScopeGC()V throws java/lang/InterruptedException 
@Lorg/junit/Test;()
  TRYCATCHBLOCK L0 L1 L2 java/lang/Exception
 L3
  LINENUMBER 10 L3
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/MemoryMXBean;
  ASTORE 1
 L4
  LINENUMBER 11 L4
  GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ALOAD 1
  INVOKEINTERFACE java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage ()Ljava/lang/management/MemoryUsage; (itf)
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  INVOKEDYNAMIC makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; [
    // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
    java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    // arguments:
    "Heap Memory Usage: \u0001"
  ]
  INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 L0
  LINENUMBER 13 L0
  LDC 100000000
  NEWARRAY T_INT
  ASTORE 2
 L1
  LINENUMBER 17 L1
  GOTO L5
 L2
  LINENUMBER 15 L2
 FRAME FULL [nl/lawinegevaar/so/GcCheck java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean] [java/lang/Exception]
  ASTORE 2
 L6
  LINENUMBER 16 L6
  NEW java/lang/RuntimeException
  DUP
  ALOAD 2
  INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/RuntimeException.<init> (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
  ATHROW
 L5
  LINENUMBER 18 L5
 FRAME SAME
  GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ALOAD 1
  INVOKEINTERFACE java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage ()Ljava/lang/management/MemoryUsage; (itf)
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  INVOKEDYNAMIC makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; [
    // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
    java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    // arguments:
    "Heap Memory Usage: \u0001"
  ]
  INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 L7
  LINENUMBER 19 L7
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/System.gc ()V
 L8
  LINENUMBER 21 L8
  LDC 5000
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Thread.sleep (J)V
 L9
  LINENUMBER 22 L9
  GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ALOAD 1
  INVOKEINTERFACE java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage ()Ljava/lang/management/MemoryUsage; (itf)
  INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  INVOKEDYNAMIC makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; [
    // handle kind 0x6 : INVOKESTATIC
    java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    // arguments:
    "Heap Memory Usage after GC: \u0001"
  ]
  INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 L10
  LINENUMBER 23 L10
  RETURN
 L11
  LOCALVARIABLE e Ljava/lang/Exception; L6 L5 2
  LOCALVARIABLE this Lnl/lawinegevaar/so/GcCheck; L3 L11 0
  LOCALVARIABLE memoryBean Ljava/lang/management/MemoryMXBean; L4 L11 1
  MAXSTACK = 3
  MAXLOCALS = 3
```

The array is allocated at `L0` and assigned to slot 2 (`ASTORE 2`). This slot is also used for `e` of the catch block as you can see at the end (`LOCALVARIABLE e Ljava/lang/Exception; L6 L5 2`); note that there is no `LOCALVARIABLE` declaration for `arr`, the compiler doesn't include it because `arr` is never used again.

In any case, because no exception is thrown, the catch block is never used, and so slot 2 is never assigned a new value, and it continues to hold a strong reference to the array until the method ends. And given that strong reference, the array cannot be garbage collected. If you add `arr = null`, the array is no longer strongly referenced, it becomes eligible for GC (and the compiler will also add a `LOCALVARIABLE arr [I L5 L1 2`).

Also, as Holger points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77645751/466862), this explanation only holds for interpreted bytecode, once the HotSpot JIT has gotten its hands on it, this may change (even up to a point that the array is never allocated!).

Comment: It should be mentioned that those `LOCALVARIABLE` entries are just debugging information, not used by the JVM and its garbage collector.

Comment: @Holger Good point, thanks.

Comment: Yep, your understanding is spot on. The variable is stored in the local variable table, and once it goes out of scope, the slot it occupies can be reused (though it doesn't imply immediate clearing, so its value may still be referenced).
I conducted an additional test: I defined a new variable outside the try-catch block, eg `int i = 1`. The result is that the `arr` object was cleaned. The javap bytecode shows that there was an additional `astore_2`.

Answer (score 4):

Variables do not get garbage collected, the garbage collector will reclaim the memory of *objects*. As explained in [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24376768/2711488), the scope of a variable only determines the validity of names, not the reachability of objects.

The array is eligible to garbage collection at the `System.gc();` call, not because the variable went out of scope but because the object is not touched by subsequent code. It would be eligible even if the variable was still in scope.

But whether or when the object will eventually get garbage collected, is up to the implementation and subject to technical details.

One detail, is the bytecode of the compiled program. The following simplified example will print its compiled form:

```java
import java.util.spi.ToolProvider;

public interface Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[] arr = new int[100000000];
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.gc();
        showBytecode();
    }
    private static void showBytecode() {
        ToolProvider.findFirst("javap").ifPresentOrElse(
            tp -> tp.run(System.out, System.err, "-c", "Main"),
            () -> System.out.println("no javap found"));
    }
}
```

<sup>[Online demo on tio.run](https://tio.run/##XVHBTsMwDL33K6KeUmmL4DzBAWncEBPjhnYIqbt6tEnkuB0T2reXtNtKiw9ObL9nPdsH3erlIf/qOqy9IxaHmFANY6WCR/XuXLUh12IOtEoS33xWaARaBiq0AfGi0YqfRES71gJrjk/rMBd1rMotE9r9x05o2ofsCu6N6TSJeot9BxyJB2HhOMT3d1fbrUbsWRjNppTrbwOe0VkB2b9WXJI7Dk3eGstYw4iVkE06jb/tKTDUam/kpBxKd3w6MRiXwy1/oXjCVjPMxp2jJ4KmW1QF2vwZKbBM@137NFNYbAgCWH6ldRVAzifxYvkYvaImLvOi0jW8uCkGooVIlyaNvj9Hmi1m/Kgk8v@IKkq3XFmZWjdc24vCNTZPs3HAc9J1vw)</sup>

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public interface Main {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #1                  // int 100000000
       2: newarray       int
       4: astore_1
       5: goto          18
       8: astore_1
       9: new           #3                  // class java/lang/RuntimeException
      12: dup
      13: aload_1
      14: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/RuntimeException."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
      17: athrow
      18: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/System.gc:()V
      21: invokestatic  #6                  // InterfaceMethod showBytecode:()V
      24: return
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           0     5     8   Class java/lang/Exception
}
```

The instruction 4, `astore_1` will store the array into local variable index 1, the non-exception code flow will follow the `goto 18` and the instruction 18 is the `System.gc()` call. There is nothing in-between to hint that the variable will be unused at this point.

As a consequence, simple interpreted execution will usually not detect that the array is unreachable at this point, which is common for code being executed a single time. JVMs like the widespread HotSpot JVM start execution in interpreted mode and compile only frequently executed code. So if you run the same method multiple times in the same JVM, you might see that the array gets garbage collected. The linked Q&A shows an example of an object getting garbage collected even when the variable is still in scope.

However, there is no guarantee. For example, `System.gc()` is only a hint to the JVM. An optimizer may even change the code to not create the array in the first place.