# Is it possible that Process is terminated after java.lang.Process local variable goes out of scope in Java?

Tags: java, process

I have a class which goal is to start a background process. This process is needed for the main functionality described in another class.

So let's say I have:

```
class ProcessStarter {
   private Process process;
   public start() {
      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder...
      process = processBuilder.start();
   }
}

class Main {
   public doSmth() {
      ProcessStarter starter = new ProcessStarter();
      starter.start();
      doSmthImportant();
   }
}
```

Now. When I make process to be a local variable:

```
class ProcessStarter {
   public start() {
      ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(...);
      Process process = processBuilder.start();
   }
}
```

then I started having issue that at the time doSmthImportant() is executed, the process has been already finished.

So does Process terminate when its variable goes out of scope?

Comment: The docs are your friend: [The subprocess is not killed when there are no more references to the Process object, but rather the subprocess continues executing asynchronously.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Comment: There is no `doMainThings` in the posted code. Further, it’s worth reading [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380219/2711488), to understand that variable scope is unrelated to the reachability of objects. So if you mean `doSmthImportant()` instead of `doMainThings()`, it doesn’t hold a reference to the process in both versions. So how do you even determine whether the process is still running during the execution of the method? Most likely by looking at side effects which have no guaranteed order in the first place…